# Rhino: restrict Java packages that can be accessed from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, sandbox, rhino

When embedding a JavaScript interpreter (Rhino) into a Java application (to be able to script that application), how would one go about restricting the Java packages that are available to scripts? For example, only "java.lang.*" should be accessible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A method for blocking access to certain packages and classes (including through reflection) in Rhino is described [here](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/01/02/sandboxing-rhino-in-java/). The important interface is [ClassShutter](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/ClassShutter.html) which provides access control for Rhino's LiveConnect support.

Comment: Ironically, the link to codeutopia.net about blocking access is returning 403 Forbidden for me

Answer (score 1):

how about just saying:

java = undefined; 
com = undefined;
Packages = undefined;

in an initial script which is loaded first.

Comment: Interesting approach, probably works if you want to turn off *all* access to Java (not just specific packages). On the other hand, you could probably still do `obj.getClass().forName("a.b.c.TheClass").newInstance()` for any object that you have in the interpreter scope.

Comment: @Thilo no if your objects are javascript objects (which is what you should do )

Comment: That is a bad idea as JavaScript methods appear to call `java.io` functions which will then fail if they can't find the `java` class. Try evaluating `print("Hello World");` after undefining `java` and see where it gets you - `TypeError: Cannot read property "io" from undefined`.