# Why is it allowed to access Java private fields via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, private-members

Consider this example :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        try {
            Field f = C.class.getDeclaredField("a");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Integer i = (Integer)f.get(c);
            System.out.println(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

class C {
    private Integer a =6;
}
```

It seems illogical that you are allowed to access private fields of classes with reflection. Why is such a functionality available? Isn't it "dangerous" to allow such access?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Private is intended to prevent accidental misuse, not as a security mechanism. If you choose to bypass it then you can do so at your own risk and the assumption you know what you are doing.

Comment: +1 perfectly right private is a hint for other programmers that they should not care about the member to keep the class running. It gives you the ability to sort your code into some contracts and have the compiler check the contract that you don't directly write or read those members. But if you have to break the contract you can do it because a programming language shouldn't stand in the way of a programmer, even if he wants to shoot himself in the knee.

Comment: so all in all, encapsulation or I should say - data hiding is all about scpoing and nothing to do with security, even if you are providing your APIs as third party jar

Answer (score 22):

Both `getDeclaredField()` and `setAccessible()` are actually checked by the security manager and will throw an exception when your code is not allowed to do this. More often than not you won't notice it, because Java code is often run without a security manager.

One important exception are Applets, which always run with a security manager.

Comment: You say that "Java code is often run without a security manager". There isn't a default security manager?

Comment: Woah ... "important" and "applet" in the same sentence. Those were the days. I'll leave it like that as a testament to how times change :-)

Answer (score 10):

Yes it's not nice but it does allow frameworks such as Java Serialization to work.

> Setting the accessible flag in a reflected object permits sophisticated applications with sufficient privilege, such as Java Object Serialization or other persistence mechanisms, to manipulate objects in a manner that would normally be prohibited.

I beleive that the functionality can be disabled through the `SecurityManager`

http://javabeans.asia/2008/10/12/how_to_set_securitymanager_and_java_security_policy_programmatically.html

Answer (score 8):

Reflection is dangerous.  Period.

What's the point in limiting the utility of a really dangerous system for the sake of ever so slightly increased safety?

Also, automated serialization requires the ability to "suck the brains" out of any class; ignoring access modifiers is a necessity in this case.

Answer (score 4):

From: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/

> Reflection is commonly used by programs which require the ability to examine or modify the runtime behavior of applications running in the Java virtual machine.

It's a tool that lets one break some rules, one can throw it over his foot or use it properly.

Answer (score 4):

Reflection is a complete API for getting inside classes. Private members and all.

In cases where you don't trust the code you're running (applets and the like) you can prevent the code from using reflection at all. See [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770635/disable-java-reflection-for-the-current-thread) for details.

Answer (score 3):

From the [description of the `java.lang.reflect`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) package:

> Classes in this package, along with
>   `java.lang.Class` accommodate
>   applications such as debuggers,
>   interpreters, object inspectors, class
>   browsers, and services such as Object
>   Serialization and JavaBeans that need
>   access to either the public members of
>   a target object (based on its runtime
>   class) or the members declared by a
>   given class.

Reflection provides a mechanism for accessing information about classes through means which are usually not available by regular interaction between classes and objects. One of such is allowing access to private fields from outside classes and objects.

Yes, reflection in general can indeed be dangerous, as it can expose the internals of classes and objects.

However, it also is a very powerful tool that can be used to inspect the internals of classes and objects, which can't be accessed by other standard means.