# Prevent or Protect Against Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying frantically to run a [programming competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25347/18487) over on the Code Golf Stack Exchange. I wrote a small control program that pits animals against each other on a game board. The animals are mostly Java classes (CrazyWolf.java, SuicideWolf.java, etc.), written by other people.

Those guys find so many loopholes in a competition that it will make your head spin. Some of them are starting to write Wolves that use reflection to cripple the competition before the simulation even begins.

I look at this from two standpoints.

- Can I protect classes in the same package against reflection?
- Can the competitors themselves protect their own Wolf against reflection?

With regard to the first question, the closest answer I could find on Stack Overflow was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/770672/3224483), which addresses restricting access to *other* packages. All of the wolves inherit from the same `Animal` class, so the class has to be accessible.

With regard to the second question, I found nothing. It seems like reflection just tramples over everything I thought I knew about private and even final variables. I did manage to find an article about tricking the compiler into replacing static final variables with a constant that won't be affected by reflection, but it seems unreliable and requires fields to be static and final.

What methods can I use to solve this? I am using Java 8 and NetBeans 7.4.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to run in a protected sandbox mode and have the security manager shut down reflection completely.

Some of the answers here may help:

[Disable Java reflection for the current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770635/disable-java-reflection-for-the-current-thread)

Comment: I linked to this answer in my question, but perhaps I didn't put enough effort into understanding what it said. I'll look at it again. You have at least given me some good terminology to search for.

Comment: Ahh yes, you linked to the answer not question so I didn't see it was the same. At its simplest try just running your code as an Applet, that will already amp the security level up enough to stop a lot of exploits. At its more complicated then google the security manager and how to configure it.